# proper way to test a service in Symfony 4, with database access

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, symfony4

What would be the proper way to test a service in Symfony 4, which also accesses the database?

I am new in Symfony4 (before I developed for Symfony2) and I want to write my first test for a Service.

This service is writing via Entities / Doctrine / ORM in the database and each of my methods, I want to test is triggering a database save.

In Symfony 2 this was the case when I used rather KernelTestCase instead of the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase because mocking the EntityManager was a pain in the ass and often I also wanted to check the result in the test db.

All examples for Symfony 4 only mention the KernelTestCase for testing Commands.

My class:

```
class UserPropertyService implements UserPropertyServiceInterface
{


    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
    ....
    }

....
}
```

My attempt at a Test:

```
class UserPropertyServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /** @var UserPropertyService */
    private $userPropertyService;

    public function setUp()
    {
        self::bootKernel();
        $client = static::createClient();
        $container = $client->getContainer();

        $this->userPropertyService = self::$container->get('app.user_management.user_property_service');
}
```

results in:

```
Cannot autowire service "App\Service\UserManagement\UserPropertyService": argument 
"$em" of method "__construct()" references class "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" 
but no such service exists. 
Try changing the  type-hint to one of its parents: interface "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface", 
or interface "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager".
```

What is the proper approach here? Which test class should I use?

Comment: This is an autowire issue not directly related to your testing setup.  Autowire is whole nother adventure in Symfony 4.  bin/console debug:container is a big help though you will need to solve this problem before the console will even run.  In particular, do as the error suggests and  change your service to typehint against EntityManagerInterface

Comment: And don't make your test code harder that it has to be.  Here is an example. https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/doctrine.html

Comment: I don't want to test doctrine. 
But my database connection has to work for being able to test the methods of my class, since beside a lot of other stuff they write to the db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how look like a service test (do not get your Container through the client, those containers are different)

By the way, you can't use `static::createClient();` if you extend from `KernelTestCase` (misunderstanding with controller test and the `WebTestCase` class ?)

```
<?php

namespace App\Tests\Service;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class UserPropertyServiceTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    /** @var UserPropertyService */
    private $myService;

    public function setUp() {
        self::bootKernel();
        $this->myService = self::$kernel->getContainer()->get('app.user_management.user_property_service');
    }

}
```